# Keras internal weights memory - why multiple fits() with one epoch still sees improvement

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, epoch

I am writing a `keras` `lstm` model in python. If I have the below `fit()` code

```
for i in range(0, epochs):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32, validation_data=[X_test, y_test], shuffle=True)
```

I would expect that each epoch is independent of the previous, i.e. there is no visible improvement with each consecutive epoch. However, this is not the case. The above code works exactly the same as writing:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=32, validation_data=[X_test, y_test], shuffle=True)
```

I know that `keras` has a `model.reset_states()` function but I don't believe that resetting the states, resets the weights, and starts a new epoch independently in the first code block. So how is `keras` saving weights and other data between independent `fit()` functions and how can I reset it?

Comment: Your whole expectation that each epoch is independent does not apply to the fit or fit_generator functions, they just do not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `fit` function is only *updating* the weights. That's why if you call `fit` several times you'll just update weights every time.

Answer (score 0):

as @Yoskutik points out, fit only updates the weights.

To reset the weights after each epoch you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf # (TensorFlow version 2.2)

# build dummy model
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,))
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='zeros')(inputs)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

# dummy data
X = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10, 20)

initial_weights = model.get_weights() # get the initial weights (in this case zeros)
for _ in range(5):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    print('weights after one epoch of training =')
    print('kernel:0 = {}'.format(np.squeeze(model.trainable_variables[0].numpy())))
    print('bias:0 = {}\n'.format(np.squeeze(model.trainable_variables[1].numpy())))
    model.set_weights(initial_weights) # set initial_weights after epoch is done

>> output:
weights after one epoch of training =
kernel:0 = 1.46999990940094
bias:0 = 0.28999999165534973

weights after one epoch of training =
kernel:0 = 1.46999990940094
bias:0 = 0.28999999165534973

weights after one epoch of training =
kernel:0 = 1.46999990940094
bias:0 = 0.28999999165534973

weights after one epoch of training =
kernel:0 = 1.46999990940094
bias:0 = 0.28999999165534973

weights after one epoch of training =
kernel:0 = 1.46999990940094
bias:0 = 0.2900000214576721
```

Hope it helps!